# How to deploy asp.net core web api in linux backend server nginx

Tags: .net, linux, asp.net-core, nginx, asp.net-core-webapi

Hello I tried so many thing but I unable to deploy .net core web api in linux nginx server side any sample i am facing some issue. I tried to created service in linux /etc/systemctl/system/... side added service file but I am getting 404 from browser while calling web api.

I Installed .net core and nginx in linux and configured but next step getting issue while deploying .net core web api.

Comment: Did you check the ASP.NET Core docs, eg [Host ASP.NET Core on Linux with Nginx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=linux-ubuntu)? The docs show several steps both in .NET code and NGINX setup. People can't uess which ones you completed or not. What did you actually try?

Comment: Does the solution below useful to you?

Answer (score 1):

The good news you can get the 404 error, it means it works fine.

The key point is we have the condition like below to check the environment is development or not.

```
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
```

We can change the environment settings or comment the condition in the code. The we can find the swagger ui page, by the way, usually we won't suggest to show the swagger page in production environment.

```
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
//if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
//{
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
//}
```